# Get attribute and assign function

Tags: jquery, html

this is what i'm trying to do.

```
<div class="submenu"><a href="#a">Home</a></div>
<div class="submenu"><a href="#b">Contact</a></div>
```

For Jquery, i use attr to get the href link of a and then extract the name of it's href, which is #a and #b if i understand it right, then i assign it with fadeOut.

```
$(".submenu").click(function(){
    var x=$(this).children("a").attr('href');
    alert(x);
    $('x').fadeOut();
```

But it doesnt work at all? Any suggestions?

Comment: When you handle the click event, the element being clicked is actually the link itself. Welcome to the _bubbling_ effect.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to perform some action to the targets of the links when they are clicked, here's what you should do:

```
//Attach the click handler to the link itself
$('.submenu a').click(function () {
    //Create a new jquery object using the link's href as the selector. eg: #a
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    //Do whatever you want to do with the element
    $target.fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: It still not work, can you check the test files for me. Thank you so much. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1z33letggqzintf/Test.zip?dl=0)

Comment: @NamDang The code works fine, in your project you have not added any `<script>` tags to the HTML to reference jquery or your custom js script file

Comment: Sorry for that. I added and still the same. When you added script link, did it work?

Comment: @NamDang yes, I just added `<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" ></script><script src="scripts/my_script.js" ></script>` to the document's head and it worked

Comment: yes,the test file worked. then there must be something wrong with the file i'm working on. Thanks you @koala_dev